# initLoader - how to handle configuration change?

Tags: java, android, android-loadermanager, onconfigurationchanged, commonsware-cwac

I am trying to use commonsware's [LoaderEx](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex) in my project. So I tested [LoaderExDemo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex/blob/master/demo/src/com/commonsware/cwac/loaderex/demo/ConstantsBrowser.java) project. It works fine. But when I change the device from portrait mode to landscape mode the [loader](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex/blob/master/demo/src/com/commonsware/cwac/loaderex/demo/ConstantsBrowser.java#L191) variable is going to be `null`.

In `onCreate` method we initialize the loader like following

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

then why `loader` is not initializing  when configuration change ? Then how to fix this ?

Logcat report

```
11-06 19:08:39.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1666): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 19:08:39.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1666): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 19:08:39.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1666):     at com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.demo.ConstantsBrowser.processAdd(ConstantsBrowser.java:176)
11-06 19:08:39.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1666):     at com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.demo.ConstantsBrowser.access$1(ConstantsBrowser.java:170)
11-06 19:08:39.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1666):     at com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.demo.ConstantsBrowser$1.onClick(ConstantsBrowser.java:134)
11-06 19:08:39.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1666):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
11-06 19:08:39.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1666):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 19:08:39.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1666):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-06 19:08:39.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1666):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-06 19:08:39.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1666):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 19:08:39.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1666):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-06 19:08:39.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1666):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-06 19:08:39.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1666):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-06 19:08:39.515: E/AndroidRuntime(1666):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, excellent point -- that's a bug in my demos.

Add the following line to `onLoadFinished()`:

```
this.loader=(SQLiteCursorLoader)loader;
```

That will be called as part of the configuration change, to deliver our last-loaded `Cursor`, and we can hold onto the `Loader` there.

I will update my repository with this fix soonish.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you change the orientation the view is recreated.

you can prevent this by adding

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

to your activity in the manifest and handle the orientation change by yourself by overriding the `onConfigurationChanged` trigger.

Comment: then what, retain the loader variable and reuse it?

Comment: No, save the `Loader` in `onLoadFinished()` -- see my answer.